# Nexus 7 debug mode connected/disconnected and vice versa

Tags: nexus-7, usb-debugging

During development on an app, i plug in the nexus 7 in my ubuntu and mac. The USB Debugging icon on the notifications always connected/disconnected and vice versa.  How do i keep this from happening and displays always in debugging mode?

i attempt to fix it by these steps:

- restarted adb
- rebooted device
- revoke usb debugging authorization

tried all of these but nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check your USB cable it must be lose.

Comment: it isn't. i've been using this right from the day i bought it since the release of 4.2 and had no issues on usb debugging